# Publishing a Python based app (runs on it own url) - on Salesforce, so users can find it on Salesforce Marketplace (appExchange) publically

Tags: python, salesforce, marketplace

We have a python fast api based application, that uses Salesforce credentials (username, password and security token) to fetch data from salesforce using SOQL queries.
I want this app to be published in Salesforce appExchange or Salesforce marketplace, so other users can find it.
How do I do this? Should I use connected apps? I also read somewhere about only API apps.

A tutorial or a head start will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to become a Salesforce partner ([Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/isvforce_basics)) to list your solution on the AppExchange, and you'll need to pass the [Security Review](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/isv_security_review?trail_id=isv_developer_beginner). If your application is paid, fees will be involved.

Note that some of the materials you'll find about AppExchange publishing will not apply to your situation as you are not building a Salesforce package, but an integrated application. You can disregard Trailhead modules on packaging.

---

Your application should be using OAuth, not raw user credentials and a security token. It is possible that this architecture will cause you to fail Security Review. (I am not a reviewer, but if I were, I would fail an application for this insecure design).

You will need to create a Connected App in a Salesforce org once you transition to using OAuth. This Connected App will identify your application.

---

*Disclosure: I am a Salesforce employee but do not work on AppExchange*.